# Quotient topology, topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

[image]

This is a practice final exam.

My questions:
1) When the question defines X/~ as quotient topology. Does that mean I can write:
$q: X \rightarrow  X/\sim  $
2) Specifically, I am trying to prove that $\bar f$ is continuous. and $\bar f$ is bijective.

Note: I have already proven that inverse of $\bar f$ is continuous.

Comment: Can you state explicitly what the function $\bar{f}$ is?  There is a canonical way to define a bijection in this problem.

Comment: Sure, f¯ : X/~ -> Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want $\bar{f}: (X/\sim) \to Y$ to be your homeomorphism, correct?  One way to define $\bar{f}$ is to let $\bar{f}([p]) = f(p)$ where $p \in X$ but $[p] \in X/\sim$.  Now if $U \subseteq Y$ then to prove $\bar{f}$ continuous we want $\bar{f}^{-1}(U)$ to be open in $X/\sim$.  This set is equivalent to writing $(q\circ f^{-1})(U)$ and this is open since both $f$ and $q$ are continuous.

Comment: I see. So you are saying that I am allowed to define a q: X -> X/~ based on what ingredients are given in the question?

Comment: @user1799252 I don't understand your question.  Because you have an equivalence relation on your points in $X$ then you can define a quotient topology $X/\sim$ by just sending each point to its representative.  If we represent the elements of $X/\sim$ as $[x]$ where $x \in X$, then we immediately have a continuous map $q: X \to X/\sim$ called the *quotient map* where $q(x) = [x]$.

Comment: I think you have answered my question just in this last reply.

But essentially, I was asking:
If the question states that Tx induces a Quotient Topology on X 
Then, am I allowed to define a q such that q: X -> X/~ and at the same time, say that q is a quotient map and q is continuous?

Comment: I have edited my reply above. :)

Comment: @user1799252 I think you are still confused a bit.  $\mathcal{T}_X$ does not induce the quotient topology, the equivalence relation $x_1 \sim x_2$ if and only if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ induces the quotient topology.  This is done by first constructing the set $X/\sim$ of equivalence classes, and then let $q:X \to X/\sim$ be the map $q(x) = [x]$.  Then we *define* the topology $\mathcal{T}_{X/\sim}$ by saying $U \in \mathcal{T}_{X/\sim}$ if and only if $q^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T}_X$.  This construction in particular makes $q$ continuous.

Comment: Your explanation is actually much clearer. My professor just stated the theorem and moved on.

Comment: I hope you wouldn't mind me asking another question that is related to the concept of homeomorphism. Say I know that two topological spaces X1 and X2 are connected, then I want to justify that X1 is not homeomorphic to X2. But professor justified this by considering: Does removing a point in X1 make X1 disconnected? How about the same for that of X2? It turns out that X1 becomes disconnected by removing a point, but not X2. And thus, X1 is not homeomorphic to X2. My question is: If you are removing a point from a space and look at that, aren't you looking at another space instead of X1 and X2?

Comment: @user1799252 Because this is a separate problem I would recommend posting this as a separate question on this site.  In addition, I would highly recommend you become familiar with the typesetting norms on Stackexchange by checking this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind sharing your knowledge, here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751874/connected-disconnencted-and-homeomorphism    :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First check (this is easy) that $\sim$ defined by $x \sim y$ iff $f(x) = f(y)$ is an equivalence relation.

So we have the set of classes $X/\sim = \{[x]: x \in X\}$ and a standard quotient map $q: X \rightarrow X/\sim$ with $q(x) = [x]$. By definition $X/\sim$ is made into a topological space by giving it the quotient topology with respect to $q$. I.e. a set $U \subseteq X/\sim$ is open exactly when $q^{-1}[U] = \{x \in X: [x] \in U \}$ is open.

Now, $\sim$ is defined by using $f$. This means that if we have any class $[x] \in X/\sim$, we can pick any point $p$ in it, and have the same value $f(p)$ regardless of the $p$ we pick, so we could pick the representative $x$ of $[x]$ and define $\tilde{f}([x]) = f(x) \in Y$. So this defines a function from the set of classes of $X$ (under $\sim$) to $Y$. And this is well-defined (if $[x] = [x']$ then this means that $x \sim x'$ and so $f(x) = f(x')$), and we get the same value.

Both $X/\sim$ and $Y$ have topologies so we can discuss continuity. If $U$ is open in $Y$, then is $\tilde{f}^{-1}[U]$ open? By the definition of the quotient topology on $X/\sim$ this is exactly the case when $q^{-1}[\tilde{f}^{-1}[U]]$ is open in $X$. And $x \in  q^{-1}[\tilde{f}^{-1}[U]]$ iff $q(x) = [x] \in \tilde{f}^{-1}[U]$ iff $\tilde{f}([x]) = f(x) \in U$ iff $x \in f^{-1}[U]$. So

$$q^{-1}[\tilde{f}^{-1}[U]] = f^{-1}[U]$$

and so this is indeed open by continuity of $f$.

$\tilde{f}$ is surjective as $f$ is surjective (check this).

$\tilde{f}$ is injective because we precisely identify values of $f$ and no more: suppose $\tilde{f}([x]) = \tilde{f}([x'])$. This means by definition of $\tilde{f}$ that $f(x) = f(x')$ and so $x \sim x'$ and thus $[x] = [x']$. So we have injectivity.

All we have used so far for $f$ is continuity and surjectivity.

If $f$ is a quotient map, then we note that for $O \subseteq X/\sim$ open, we have that $f^{-1}[\tilde{f}[O]] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in \tilde{f}[O]\}$ just equals $q^{-1}[O]$ (check this!) and so is open by continuity of $q$, and as $f$ is a quotient map, $\tilde{f}[O]$ is then open in $Y$. This makes $\tilde{f}$ an open, continuous, bijection so a homeomorphism between $X /\sim$ and $Y$.

Your fact is a special case, as a continuous surjection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed, and so in particular a quotient map.