# Connected, disconnencted, and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Say X = [0,1]
T be the subspace topology induced on X, coming from the Standard Topology on R

$$ Y = S^{1} $$ and T' be the subspace topology on Y, coming from the Standard Topology on $$ R^{2} $$

I have shown that X and Y are connected and compact.

To show that X is not homeomorphic to Y, my professor considered the following:
Removing a point from X makes it disconnected, but removing a point does not make Y disconnected.

So X is not homeomorphic to Y.

My question: Why are we allowed to do that? Aren't removing a point from X (or Y) meaning that we are considering a different space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you’re looking at different spaces, but that’s not a problem.

Perhaps it would help to add the missing details in your professor’s argument. Suppose that $h:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism. Then for any $A\subseteq X$, the restriction $h\upharpoonright A$ is a homeomorphism from $A$ to $h[A]$. In particular, if $A=X\setminus\left\{\frac12\right\}$, let $p=h\left(\frac12\right)$, let $B=Y\setminus\{p\}$, and let $f=h\upharpoonright A$; then $f$ is a homeomorphism from $A$ to $B$. But this is impossible, because $B$ is connected and $A$ is not: they cannot be homeomorphic spaces.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @user1799252: You’re very welcome.